# asp.net Application object locking

Tags: asp.net, locking

I am converting an application from one framework to another, and have a question about the Application object.

I have some data (< 1MB) that gets read when the application starts, and almost never updated on disk.  (e.g. years between changes)  The data is accessed *very* frequently -- at least once per page load, but usually multiple times, and always for *reading* only.

I think shoving this data into the Application object on startup (in the Global.asax in Application_Start) is probably the right thing to do.  My question is, will I need to lock around the object?  (`Application.Lock`/`Application.Unlock`)  Since the `Application_Start` method fires only once, and every other access is reading, can I get away without locks here?

[Why not use web.config?  The data's rather unsuited for a web.config file, and I'd like the data left the way it is because it's also shared with other non ASP.NET applications.]

Answer (score -1):

Locks are meant for applications where you read and write at the same time, so if you're going to read only, you don't need locks.